# In Photoshop, what's the difference between Save (or Save As) and Export?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The question arises because "Save as" and "Export" shares several options for the file destination's format.

So, when I should use "Save as" and when "Export"?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I look at these two options when I'm working in Photoshop...

"Export" is my method for saving a file that needs to be optimized for transmission over a low data-rate medium (like the internet). Adobe explains the "Export" feature like this...

> "A redesigned exporting experience lets you export a single layer,
>   artboard or entire document with one click. Plus, get better
>   compression, advanced preview options that include canvas size and
>   enhanced asset extraction. It’s a modernized Save for Web experience."

"Save As" is my standard method for generating final image files in a variety of formats (including some that are available in "Export"), while retaining maximum file information and metadata. When I'm using "Save As" I'm primarily interested in retaining a file with the best quality (in a particular format), not reducing/optimizing the file size.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is different...When I SaveAs to jpg I get a file size about half the size of the same when Exported.  So I generally always export files sent to print.

Comment: Hello and welcome to GDSE. You are answering a question which is 4 years old. While we welcome answers about updated software or methodologies, we also want them to be substantiated and in-depth. Your answer does not really contribute anything to the previous answer.